# Acessando método (iniciante)

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo, padrão-dao

Comecei meus estudos recentemente e surgiu uma dúvida com relação ao acesso de informações de um método. Eu tenho um arquivo X.php que possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
public function selectDB($sql,$params=null,$class=null){
    $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);

    $total_q = $query->rowCount();


    if(isset($class)){
        $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,$class) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
    }else{
        $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
    }
    self::__destruct();
    return $rs;
}
```

E possuo uma página Y.php que faz uso desta função. Como que eu faço para que na página Y.php seja exibido o valor da variável `$total_q` ?

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz por favor?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode chamar o arquivo X.php no Y.php a forma que você vai utilizar depende de como pretende utilizar o arquivo X.php
Podendo utilizar:
include 'X.php'; 
require 'X.php'; 
require_once 'X.php';

A escolha do método a utilizar é sua mas basicamente é referente ao tratamento de erros, no include ele apenas exibe um warning e continua a execução do script, no require ele para a execução se der algum erro no codigo

Comment: No caso eu o chamo com um include. O problema, é que quando mando dar o echo na variável, não exibe nada. Mas se eu estiver no X.php e faço o echo, o resultado aparece normalmente.

Comment: Perdão pelo vacilo, não tinha notado uma coisa. A variável $total_q esta dentro de uma função ou seja ela esta em escopo local, (só existe dentro da função). Coloque $total_q como retorno da função selectDB também, recomendo utilizar um array

Comment: Guilherme, muito obrigado. Eu declarei como variável global, e deu certo. Obrigado mesmo. Abs,